# Postgresql Oracle_fdw

Tags: postgresql, oracle

Доброго дня. Пытаюсь подключиться к Oracle из Postgres через расширение Oracle_fdw
Isql и SqlPlus подключаются.

```
CREATE SERVER Oracle FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw          
OPTIONS (dbserver 'mthbz');
    GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER Oracle TO Postgres;
    CREATE USER MAPPING FOR Postgres SERVER Oracle
              OPTIONS (user 'dan', password 'dan');
     CREATE FOREIGN TABLE Oracle_fdw(
             create foreign table WEBDISPETCHER ( 
             ID INTEGER 
        ,FurnLoadNumbermelt INTEGER 
        ,SundWorkComp5 INTEGER 
        ,SundWorkComp6 INTEGER 
        ,MeltCountA INTEGER 
        ,MeltCountB INTEGER 
        ,CountStoppageA INTEGER 
        ,CountStoppageB INTEGER 
        ,defectA INTEGER 
        ,defectB INTEGER 
        ,StartTeam TEXT
        ,DateTimeServer TEXT
        ,FurnLoadSteel CHAR(15) 
        ,FurnLoadProfile CHAR(5) 
        ,MeltTimeStartStoppageA VARCHAR(25) 
        ,MeltTimeStartStoppageB VARCHAR(25) 
        ,FurnPressureA INTEGER 
        ,FurnPressureB INTEGER 
        ,FurnOnloadMelt INTEGER 
        ,FurnOnloadSteel CHAR(15) 
        ,FurnOnloadProfile CHAR(5) 
        ,FurnGasConsumption INTEGER 
        ,MeltNumberMeltA INTEGER 
        ,MeltNumberMeltB INTEGER 
        ,MeltSteelA CHAR(15) 
        ,MeltSteelB CHAR(15) 
        ,MeltProfileA CHAR(5) 
        ,MeltProfileB CHAR(5) 
        ,MeltTempInletStandA INTEGER 
        ,MeltTempInletStandB INTEGER 
        ,MeltInletFFBA INTEGER 
        ,MeltInletFFBB INTEGER 
        ,MeltOutWBA INTEGER 
        ,MeltOutWBB INTEGER 
        ,MeltSpeedRollA REAL 
        ,MeltSpeedRollB REAL ) 
    server oracle options (schema 'dan', table 'WEBDISPETCHER');
```

При запросе Select * from oracle_fdw;

```
ERROR:  connection for foreign table "oracle_fdw" cannot be established
DETAIL:  ORA-12154: TNS:невозможно разрешить заданный идентификатор соединения
********** Ошибка **********

ERROR: connection for foreign table "oracle_fdw" cannot be established
SQL-состояние: HV00N
Подробности: ORA-12154: TNS:невозможно разрешить заданный идентификатор соединения
```

Comment: У вас команды как-то в кучу. Где вы указали на каком ip или hostname расположена база oracle? Этот хост с хоста postgresql пингуется?

Comment: CREATE SERVER Oracle FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw          
OPTIONS (dbserver 'mthbz'); mthbz это имя указанное в Tnsnames.ora пинг от Postgres до Oracla идёт отлично. По поводу OPTIONS (dbserver 'mthbz');  пробывал много вариантов \\10.98.10.20\mthbz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было использовать

```
CREATE SERVER Oracle FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw          
OPTIONS (dbserver '\\ip\dbname');
```